# Firefox is not displaying GitHub pages properly

Tags: macos, firefox, github

Firefox is not displaying github pages properly. Tried clearing cache and it didn't help. Version is 99.0.1 (64-bit). How can I fix it? Rest all sites are working fine, only the github pages are getting dispalyed like below:
[image]

And it doesn’t show as expected for public GitHub repos [like this one](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs/):
[image]

Comment: Seems like the CSS and perhaps other assets on the page are not properly loading. Based on [the URL in your screenshot](https://github.com/argoproi), this seems to be a private repo. Has the page ever worked before? What about other GitHub pages like [this one](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs/)?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 It is similar to all/any github pages. I  have updated with github link you gave

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some files aren't loading.

Press `F12` to open the developer tools. Select the [network tab](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/_images/network_monitor_closeup.png). Look for files which don't have a green status code.

You can also look into the console tab for errors.